# Can I load modules on runtime? Angular 2

Tags: angular

So I have basic angular app with links. By clicking the link user download angular 2 module with all dependencies (typescript files or compiled js files, choose one to make it work). After download is finished, this basic app injects module and start it (assume we have specified entry point for such downloaded modules). It sounds pretty the same as plugin system, but in web and during current session only. Can I somehow achive this in angular 2? Thanks

Comment: you mean reinvent browser cache ? :-D Actually I don't understand your question.

Comment: @n00dl3 I mean somehow inject a module, current client app has no idea about. If some operations with browser cache will do the trick, I am glad to here about this solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Loading modules dynamically from a given folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039825/angular2-loading-modules-dynamically-from-a-given-folder)

Comment: ok I dind't get it... just thought you wanted to not reload your modules every time. Do you mean load modules asynchronously depending on the route ? that's [supported out of the box](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#asynchronous-routing).

Comment: @n00dl3 No, lazy loading assumes that I declared module somewhere in app.module and it is compiled. But what I want is: app knows only path to independend module files (my.module.ts, my.component.ts etc or similar js files (compiled on server side)). And by clicking button or something, app loads this module, like LoadAssembly in c#, and start its main component (lets say that out app knows this main component by name for example)

Comment: "app knows only path to independend module files(...) And by clicking button or something, app loads this module" that's lazy-loading, and that's exactly what I described and what the links points to in the docs.

Comment: oh, thanks @n00dl3

Comment: @n00dl3 yes it is lazy loading, however not for "routing" modules but for completely independent module compiled in an another project.

Comment: @shumantt did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @shumantt, did you find some solution for this? If yes could you please help me on this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can lazy load any module with angular-router

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

Comment: I repeat it here to make it clear: Lazy loading assumes that I declared module somewhere in app.module. But what I want is: app knows only path to independend module files (my.module.ts, my.component.ts etc or similar js files (compiled on server side)). And by clicking button or something, app loads this module, like LoadAssembly in c#, and start its main component (lets say that out app knows this main component by name for example)

Comment: If you declare that module in the app then its not lazy loading nor dynamic in any sense. If you do Typescript will require the module-name as well as where its located